# Comma or not? Question or Period?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, sentence, writing

> Before[...] you asked if I was _____.

Should there be a comma after 'before' or is the ellipsis okay? Also, should the sentence end with a period or a question mark?

Comment: You might also need to change *was* to *were* since this looks like reported speech.

Answer (score 1):

**Comma?**

Is "before" an adverb or a conjunction here? To avoid this ambiguity:

If an adverb, then comma.

If a conjunction, then no comma.

**Period or Question Mark**

Is this a statement or a question?

If "before" is an adverb, then it is a statement, and a period is required.

Example:

*Before, veronicaaxo asked if a comma is required.*

If "before" is a conjunction, we need to know what follows because the "before" clause is a dependent clause:

Examples:

*Before veronicaaxo asked if a comma is required, what was veronicaaxo doing?*

*Before veronicaaxo asked if a comma is required, veronicaaxo was having dinner.*

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/before

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that you can use both, because if you use a comma, it would show the speaker as a more bold and direct person. If you use the three dots, it shows that there was more of a pause from the speaker. If you were to use this for your English teacher, I advise you not to, since the three dots aren't very formal. I hope that helped a bit?